# SQL - Trigger to check insert of date on each student

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, database-trigger

I'm trying to create a trigger that check the date that I'm inserting is greater than the one present in table for each student. The control need to be only on ID and DATE.

**STUDENT_EXAMS**

```
id_student subject    mark        date_exam
1          Chemistry  6          'May-05-2020'
2          Maths      7          'May-01-2020'
```

**LEGITIMATE INSERT**

```
insert into STUDENT_EXAMS (id_student, subject, mark, date_exam)
values (1, 'History', 8, 'May-06-2020');

insert into STUDENT_EXAMS (id_student, subject, mark, date_exam)
values (2, 'Biology', 8, 'May-05-2020');
```

**ILLEGITIMATE INSERT**

```
insert into STUDENT_EXAMS (id_student, subject, mark, date_exam)
values (1, 'History', 8, 'May-04-2020');

insert into STUDENT_EXAMS (id_student, subject, mark, date_exam)
values (2, 'Biology', 10, 'Apr-30-2020');
```

This is the trigger that I tried to create, but it's not working and I don't know how to insert also a control on each ID_STUDENT.

```
create or replace trigger check_date
before insert on STUDENT_EXAM
for each row
begin
    if (:new.date_exam > :old.date_exam) then
        insert into STUDENT_EXAM (id_student, subject, mark, date_exam)
        values (:new.id_student, :new.subject, :new.mark, :new.date_exam); 
end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is the one that you are interested in.It prevents insertion to STUDENT_EXAM table when date_Exam for row being inserted is less than max value of date_Exam for the id.

```
  create or replace trigger check_date
    before insert on STUDENT_EXAM
    for each row
    DECLARE 

    lv_date_exam DATE;
    begin

         select max(date_exam) into lv_date_exam 
         from student_exam where id = :new.id;

        if (:new.date_exam < lv_date_exam) then
           raise_application_error(-20000
            , 'Cannot insert record as date_exam '||:new.date_exam||' is less than max date_exam '||lv_date_exam);
    end if;
    end;
```

---

**[EDITED by Littlefoot, to show *why* it will fail with the *mutating table* error]**

Table & trigger you suggested:

```
SQL> create table student_exam (id number, date_exam date);

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger check_date
  2      before insert on STUDENT_EXAM
  3      for each row
  4      DECLARE
  5
  6      lv_date_exam DATE;
  7      begin
  8
  9           select max(date_exam) into lv_date_exam
 10           from student_exam where id = :new.id;
 11
 12          if (:new.date_exam < lv_date_exam) then
 13             raise_application_error(-20000
 14              , 'Cannot insert record as date_exam '||:new.date_exam||' is less than max date_exam '||lv_date_exam);
 15      end if;
 16      end;
 17  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

This works:

```
SQL> insert into student_exam (id, date_exam) values (1, sysdate);

1 row created.
```

But this does not:

```
SQL> insert into student_exam (id, date_exam)
  2    select 1, sysdate - 10 from dual union all
  3    select 1, sysdate + 20 from dual;
insert into student_exam (id, date_exam)
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04091: table SCOTT.STUDENT_EXAM is mutating, trigger/function may not see
it
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.CHECK_DATE", line 6
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.CHECK_DATE'


SQL>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it miserably fails with the *mutating table* error.

Comment: @Littlefoot, can you explain please why it will not work? Because I'm testing it and for now seems works, thanks for the help!

Comment: @Gwynbleidd, I edited the author's message by adding example which shows *why*. VN'sCorner, feel free to rollback that edit. I'm not posting an *answer*, just trying to explain what's wrong with it.